# Flat an array tree js

Tags: javascript, arrays, flat

Can you help me please to flat this tree?
I have tried a few things and it didn't work.
I would like to get the fastest way(Algorithm).

```
const source = [
  {
    item: { id: 1, name: "item name", code: "1d4g4" },
    children: [
      {
        item: { id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" },
        children: [
          {
            item: { id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" },
            children: [
              {
                item: { id: 3, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" },
                children: [
                  { item: { id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [] },
                  { item: { id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [] },
                  { item: { id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [] },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

This is result that i expect to have:

````
  { id: 1, name: 'item name', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 2, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 2, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 3, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' }
]```
````

Comment: If you say you tried something, you need to show us what you tried.  Otherwise you're asking us to provide a complete solution.

Comment: *"I have tried a few things"* ~ What are these things you have tried?

Comment: There's a function on arrays named [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)...

Comment: Are the final three items supposed to all have the same ID?

Comment: Your source isn't valid JavaScript.

Comment: What is your expected output here @Vadim ?

Comment: The absolute bare minimum requirement when asking a question is posting compilable data. There are missing `{}` brackets after `children: [` in your data. Any IDE will highlight these errors. Please create a [mcve] by posting a valid array of objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing your syntax to be actually valid JavaScript, you'll need a recursive function:

```
function flatten(destArray, nodeList) {
  nodeList.forEach((node) => {
    destArray.push(node.item);
    flatten(destArray, node.children || []);
  });
}

const source = [
  {
    item: { id: 1, name: "item name", code: "1d4g4" },
    children: [
      {
        item: { id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" },
        children: [
          {
            item: { id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" },
            children: [
              {
                item: { id: 3, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" },
                children: [
                  { item: { id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [] },
                  { item: { id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [] },
                  { item: { id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [] },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

const dest = [];
flatten(dest, source);
console.log(dest);
```

outputs

```
[
  { id: 1, name: 'item name', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 2, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 2, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 3, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' },
  { id: 4, name: 'item name 2', code: '1d4g4' }
]
```

Comment: I had it before my bad

Answer (score 3):

You could take [`Array#flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and a callback which calls itself.

```js
const
    flat = ({ item, children = [] }) => [item, ...children.flatMap(flat)],
    data = [{ item: { id: 1, name: "item name", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [{ item: { id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [{ item: { id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [{ item: { id: 3, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [{ item: { id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [] }, { item: { id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [] }, { item: { id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4" }, children: [] }] }] }] }] }],
    result = data.flatMap(flat);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an internal `visit` method to handle traversing the tree and adding items to an internal `results` list.

**Note:** Make sure your JS/JSON data is structured correctly.

```js
const tree = [{
  item: {id: 1, name: "item name", code: "1d4g4"},
  children: [{
    item: {id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"},
    children: [{
      item: {id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"},
      children: [{
        item: {id: 3, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"},
        children:[
          {item: {id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"}, children: []},
          {item: {id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"}, children: []},
          {item: {id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"}, children: []},
        ]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];

const treeToList = (tree, results = []) => {
  const visit = ({ item, children = [] }, res) => {
    if (item) res.push(item);
    children.forEach(child => visit(child, res));
  }
  visit({ children: tree }, results);
  return results;
}

console.log(treeToList(tree));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> const flatten = (data) => data.map(({ children }) => ([...flatten(children)]));
> ```

Your current code does traverse the whole tree, but never actually extracts `item` from the data. Another issue is that you currently use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), which means the resulting value will always have the same amount of elements as the initial array. Use [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to increase or reduce the amount of elements in the array.

Changing your code as little as possible it might look like this:

```
const flatten = (data) => data.flatMap(({item, children}) => ([item, ...flatten(children)]));
```

```js
const flatten = (data) => data.flatMap(({item, children}) => ([item, ...flatten(children)]));

const data = [{
  item: {id: 1, name: "item name", code: "1d4g4"},
  children: [{
    item: {id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"},
    children: [{
      item: {id: 2, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"},
      children: [{
        item: {id: 3, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"},
        children:[
          {item: {id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"}, children: []},
          {item: {id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"}, children: []},
          {item: {id: 4, name: "item name 2", code: "1d4g4"}, children: []},
        ]
      }]
    }]
  }]
}];

console.log(flatten(data));
```