# flatten tree structure into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree, tree-structure

I have this tree structure:

```
    data = 
    {
     [
       {
        type: "folder"
        name: "animals"
        path: "/animals"
        children  :
          [
            {
            type: "folder"
            name: "cat"
            path: "/animals/cat"
            children:
              [
                {
                  type: "folder"
                  name: "images"
                  path: "/animals/cat/images"
                  children: 
                    [
                      {
                        type: "file"
                        name: "cat001.jpg"
                        path: "/animals/cat/images/cat001.jpg"
                      },
                      {
                        type: "file"
                        name: "cat001.jpg"
                        path: "/animals/cat/images/cat002.jpg"
                      }
                    ]
                }
              ]
            }
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

I want to turn it into

```
[
  {
    type: "folder"
    name: "animals"
    path: "/animals"
  },
  {
    type: "folder"
    name: "cat"
    path: "/animals/cat"
  },
  {
    type: "folder"
    name: "images"
    path: "/animals/cat/images"
  },
  {
    type: "file"
    name: "cat001.jpg"
    path: "/animals/cat/images/cat001.jpg"
  },
  {
    type: "file"
    name: "cat001.jpg"
    path: "/animals/cat/images/cat002.jpg"
  }
]
```

I came up with this function, but seems does not work

```
    function flatten(nodes, flattedNodes) {
      for (let index = 0; index < nodes.length; index++) {
        flattedNodes.push(nodes[index]);
        if (nodes[index].children !== undefined)
        if (nodes[index].children.length > 0)
          flatten(nodes[index].children, flattedNodes);
      }
    }

  let flattedTree = [];
  flatten(data, flattedTree);

  console.log(JSON.stringify(flattedTree, null, 4));
```

It does not flatten some elements. Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: ~9k and yet only _"seems does not work"_ as description of the problem... -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it"_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flat an array tree js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362132/flat-an-array-tree-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) and recursion:

```
const flatten = (array) => array.flatMap(({ type, name, path, children }) => [
  { type, name, path },
  ...flatten(children || [])
]);
```

---

**Complete snippet:**

```js
const data = [{
  type: "folder",
  name: "animals",
  path: "/animals",
  children: [{
    type: "folder",
    name: "cat",
    path: "/animals/cat",
    children: [{
      type: "folder",
      name: "images",
      path: "/animals/cat/images",
      children: [{
          type: "file",
          name: "cat001.jpg",
          path: "/animals/cat/images/cat001.jpg"
        }, {
          type: "file",
          name: "cat001.jpg",
          path: "/animals/cat/images/cat002.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }]
  }]
}];

const flatten = (array) => array.flatMap(({type, name, path, children}) => [
  { type, name, path },
  ...flatten(children || [])
]);

console.log(flatten(data));
```